# Does a straight water hose issue water at a greater pressure than a Coiled water hose of same diameter and length?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a one BHP water pump, the water pressure of a coiled hose connected to the water pump output side was not that great. Would an unwound water hose produce greater water pressure? [Friction Losses?]

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Hi Alan. I hope you now have sufficient reputation to be able to comment . If you are satisfied with the answer you are supposed to accept it by checking it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but under normal circumstances (e.g. garden hose scale) you wouldn't notice.

Friction losses are higher in bends, especially sharp bends, but the coils in a regular hose aren't very sharp. This is by design: hoses are made fairly sturdy so you don't get unintentional sharp bends. So it's really down to engineering more than physics.

Comment: @AlaN Jones tried to comment :"I did unwind the hose, found pressure increase. Thanks for your answer" . There was some mixup with the account.